# Executar função ao chegar na Div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs

Há como executar uma função somente quando uma `div` estiver na tela do usuário?

Exemplo, tenho uma `div` que está no meio do site e quando usuário rolar até ela, ou chegar até ela, quero que uma função seja executada.

Há como fazer isto com AngularJS ou Jquery?

Answer (score 1):

O exemplo abaixo tem a div `#box` oculta com `opacity:0`, quando chegar o scroll ao meio da div `#box` troco a opacidade para 1;

```js
var executou = false;
  $(document).scroll(function() {
      if (!executou && $(window).scrollTop() > $('#box').offset().top/2) {
          $('#box').css('opacity','1');
          executou = true;
      }
  });
```

```css
#base{
  min-height:600px
}

#box{
transition:1s;
min-height:300px;
margin-top:100%;
background:red;
opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="base">
  <div id="box">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130/check-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom#answer-3898152) do SOen serve para você:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
       alert("near bottom!");
   }
});
```

-100 é o valor relativo ao `height` que vai disparar o evento.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/gWD66/1/) por [Nick Craver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13249/nick-craver)